# некорректная работа деления в php (joomla + JBZoo)

Tags: php, joomla

в магазине  потребовалось вывести 2 цены, в текущей валюте и в "деноминированной" рядом.
в корзине сделать получилось, а в карточке товара нет
исходник корзины

```html
if ((int)$params->get('summa_show', 1)) {
echo '<p class="uk-margin-remove"><span class="price-total-value uk-text-small">' . $zoo->jbmoney->toFormat($summa, $currency) . '</span></p>';
}
```

корзина с двумя ценами работает

```html
if ((int)$params->get('summa_show', 1)) {
echo '<p class="uk-margin-remove vitaly-go-price"><span class="price-total-value uk-text-small">' . $zoo->jbmoney->toFormat($summa, $currency) . '</br><i>&nbsp;' . ($summa / 10000) . 'руб.</i></span></p>';
}
```

карточка товара оригинал

```html
<?php if ($discount[ 'value']==0 ) : ?>
<span class="total uk-text-bold"><?php echo $base['total']; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

карточка товара не работает

```html
<?php if ($discount[ 'value']==0 ) : ?>
<span class="total uk-text-bold"><?php echo $base['total'] / 10000; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

в итоге в карточке товара выводиться значительно меньшее значение чем положено
например оригинальная цена 2561000р.
цена после некорректного деления 0.0002
цена требуемая 256.1р.
и помимо некорректного деления пропадает и "р."
как это исправить не могу найти в чем проблема

Comment: Пхоже вы 2 раза делите. Один раз где-то по коду а второй в темплейте.

Comment: нет, не в этом дело, я пришел к выводу что у меня под деление попадает только 1 цифра, то есть если цена 6 321 000 руб, делится только 6, а далее идет пробел и после него все остальные символы не попадают под деление. По сути я делю не цену из прайса а цену которая уже чем то обработана на момент добавления пробелов "для красоты".

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь строку поделить на число.
Идеально надо поделить исходное неформатированную цену.

Если не получится, то используйте этот код

```
    <?php if ($discount[ 'value']==0 ) : ?>
    <span class="total uk-text-bold"><?php echo str_replace(' ', '', $base['total']) / 10000; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
```